# single-row subquery returns more than one row PROBLEM

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE tw_edu_infra_amenities
   SET new_date =
       (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(updated_date,
                                                  'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM'),
                                     'YYYYMMDD'),
                             1,
                             4) = '0021' THEN
                  REPLACE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(updated_date,
                                               'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM'),
                                  'YYYYMMDD'),
                          '0021',
                          '2021')
               END
          FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities);
```

I want to update new_date(all rows) with respect to update_date(Column) which has multiple rows. I'am getting

> single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Doesn't the table have a key column such as `id`? It's expected to be used to match the outer statement with the subquery.

Comment: What is UPDATED_DATE column's **datatype**? Looks like it is a VARCHAR2, according to your code (as you're first converting it to a timestamp, then back to character). Please, post several sample values so that we'd see what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
UPDATE tw_edu_infra_amenities
SET new_date =   REPLACE(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(updated_date,'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM'), 'YYYYMMDD'),'0021', '2021')
WHERE SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(updated_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM'),'YYYYMMDD'),1,4) = '0021'
```

The idea is to filter the rows you are interested in and then to perform the update for the given row.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tw_edu_infra_amenities SET NEW_DATE =
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(SUBSTR(UPDATED_DATE,1,8),'DD/MM/RRRR' ),'RRRRMMDD'));

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update `new_date`. In order to get the new value you select all rows of the table (because your subquery has no `WHERE` clause). Is this necessary? Does a row's `new_date` depend on all rows of the table? This does not seem likely.

You then look at all `updated_date`. Those that contain '0021', get changed to '2021'. Those that don't, get changed to NULL (because your `CASE` expression has no `ELSE` clause and NULL is the default).

With this list of date strings and nulls, what do you want to do? You try to assign the list to the row's `new_date`. But there is only room for a single value. Which one? You'd have to aggregate your list to a single row, e.g. by applying `MAX` or `MIN`.

It seems to me, you really only want to replace all 0021 years to 2021, but then you explictily say that you want to update `new_date` with respect to `update_date` of "multiple rows".

Hadn't you said so, I would have guessed you merely wanted:

```
update tw_edu_infra_amenities
set new_date = substr(updated_date, 1, 6) || '2021' || substr(updated_date, 11)
where updated_date like '______0021%';
```

Why are `new_date` and `updated_date` string columns anyway? Why don't you use an appropriate data type like `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`? You should fix this in your data model in order to ensure only valid dates can be stored.